Rotate PSTricks Object
Consider the following (almost) MWE:
% lualatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \psset{unit = 0.4}
  \begin{pspicture}(-12,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})(12,\fpeval{6*sqrt(3)})
    \pnodes
      (0,0){O}
      (-6,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)}){A}
      (-3,\fpeval{-3*sqrt(3)}){B}
      ( 3,\fpeval{-3*sqrt(3)}){C}
      ( 6,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)}){D}
    \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)(D)
    \psrotate(O){60}{\pspolygon(A)(B)(C)(D)}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

When I compile using lualatex the new, rotated trapezoid isn't drawn.
How do I draw the rotation object and what is wrong with the code above?
Update
Here is what I ended up with:
% lualatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\Ax{6 }
\def\Ay{0 }
\def\Bx{3 }
\def\By{\fpeval{3*sqrt(3)} }
\def\Cx{\fpeval{2*\Bx} }
\def\Cy{\fpeval{2*\By} }
\def\Dx{\fpeval{2*\Ax} }
\def\Dy{\fpeval{2*\Ay} }
 \centering
 \psset{unit = 0.64}
  \begin{pspicture}(-12,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})(12,\fpeval{6*sqrt(3)})
    \pnodes
      (!\Bx \By){I1}
      (!\Bx \By neg){I5}
      (!\Ax \Ay){I6}
      (!2 \Bx mul 2 \By mul){Y1}
      (!2 \Bx mul 2 \By mul neg){Y5}
      (!2 \Ax mul 2 \Ay mul){Y6}
    \multido
      {\i = 0+60}
      {6}
      {\psrotate(0,0){\i}{
         \pspolygon[
           linejoin = 1,
           fillstyle = solid,
           fillcolor = blue!40!white
         ](\Ax,\Ay)(\Bx,\By)(\Cx,\Cy)(\Dx,\Dy)
%         \psdots(\Bx,\By)(\Cx,\Cy)
       }}
    \pstMarkAngle{I5}{I6}{Y6}{\ang{120}}
    \pstMarkAngle{Y6}{I6}{I1}{\ang{120}}
    \pstMarkAngle{I6}{Y6}{Y5}{\ang{60}}
    \pstMarkAngle{Y1}{Y6}{I6}{\ang{60}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

P.S. The PostScript notation was just for myself, to see if I could remember how to use it.

The nodes aren't rotated. You should follow a similar trick you did here: Rotate PSTricks Object: Label Positioning; define variables for the positions and use those, as they will be rotated.

@Werner I've tried that in the updated question but to no good. :-(

I know precisely zilch about pstricks, so @Werner please correct me, but you're using fixed points rather than coordinates in the rotation. It seems to me for the coordinates to be rotated, you must specify them as coordinates and not as already-fixed points.

@SvendTveskæg: You did it a bit differently to what I linked to (you should use the coordinates in the \psrotated \pspolygon, not the nodes. Setting a node makes it immutable (= fixed). So, the rotation can't apply to the named point. I'm sure there is some internal update to pstricks that could allow for this, but not currently.

@Werner Thanks for the explanation!

Like this?

Note that all I did was follow Werner's link, copy Bernard's code, minimise your example and compare. I couldn't draw anything in pstricks if my life depended on it. Caveat emptor.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% addaswyd o ateb Bernard: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313389/
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
{\def\IAx{\fpeval{ 6*cosd( 60)}}%
\def\IAy{\fpeval{ 6*sind( 60)}}%
\def\IFx{\fpeval{ 6*cosd(360)}}%
\def\IFy{\fpeval{ 6*sind(360)}}%
\def\YAx{\fpeval{12*cosd( 60)}}%
\def\YAy{\fpeval{12*sind( 60)}}%
\def\YFx{\fpeval{12*cosd(360)}}%
\def\YFy{\fpeval{12*sind(360)}}%
\psset{unit = 0.4}%
\begin{pspicture}(-12,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})(12,\fpeval{6*sqrt(3)})
  \pnodes
    (0,0){O}
    (\IAx,\IAy){IA}
    (\IFx,\IFy){IF}
    (\YAx,\YAy){YA}
    (\YFx,\YFy){YF}
  \pspolygon[linecolor=red](YF)(IF)(IA)(YA)
  \psrotate(O){60}{\pspolygon[linecolor=blue](\YFx,\YFy)(\IFx,\IFy)(\IAx,\IAy)(\YAx,\YAy)}
\end{pspicture}}


\end{document}


I don't understand why I can't use the \pnodes at points when rotating an object, but your code works just fine, so thanks alot! :-)

@SvendTveskæg If you'd rather I remove this and see if somebody who can answer that explains, just let me know (and unaccept or I can't delete). I was guessing it was similar to pgf/tikz, which is why I tried this. In pgf, a coordinate transformation never changes named points, but only points specified by coordinates. That's often handy, but not in a case like this. I know that pgf/tikz often works similarly to pstricks, so I figured this might be such a case. But I haven't done anything radical such as read the docs or anything :-).

You don't have to delete your answer. Since your modifications made the code work as I hoped for, I'll keep your answer as the accepted one. :-)

That does not work with an object defined by nodes.
% lualatex test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\myPolygon#1{\pspolygon[linecolor=#1]
    (-6,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})
    (-3,\fpeval{-3*sqrt(3)})
    ( 3,\fpeval{-3*sqrt(3)})
    ( 6,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})}

\begin{document}
    
 \psset{unit = 0.4}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-12,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})(12,\fpeval{6*sqrt(3)})
  \myPolygon{black}
  \psrotate(0,0){60}{\myPolygon{red}}
  \psrotate(0,0){120}{\myPolygon{green}}
  \psrotate(0,0){180}{\myPolygon{blue}}
  \psdot(O)
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}


if you still need nodes for the coordinates, use:
    \begin{pspicture}(-12,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})(12,\fpeval{6*sqrt(3)})
        \pnodes{A}
        (0,0)
        (-6,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})
        (-3,\fpeval{-3*sqrt(3)})
        ( 3,\fpeval{-3*sqrt(3)})
        ( 6,\fpeval{-6*sqrt(3)})
        \pspolygon(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)
        \multido{\iA=1+1}{4}{\psRelLine[angle=60,linestyle=none](A0)(A\iA){1}{a\iA}}
        \pspolygon[linecolor=red](a1)(a2)(a3)(a4)
        \multido{\iA=1+1}{4}{\psRelLine[angle=120,linestyle=none](A0)(A\iA){1}{a\iA}}
        \pspolygon[linecolor=green](a1)(a2)(a3)(a4)
        \multido{\iA=1+1}{4}{\psRelLine[angle=180,linestyle=none](A0)(A\iA){1}{a\iA}}
        \pspolygon[linecolor=blue](a1)(a2)(a3)(a4)
    \end{pspicture}

